# Как получить исполняемый файл java-приложения?

Tags: macos, java, intellij-idea

Я новичок в мире Java, но так как знаком c C++, то и тут немного уже ориентируюсь. Я создал простое диалоговое приложение в среде IDEA и сразу вопрос: как мне получить исполняемый файл *.app* (работаю в OS X) своего приложения. Или если быть более конкретным - как мне запустить программу на другой машине?
Моя программа:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Dialog extends JDialog {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton buttonOK;
    private JButton buttonCancel;

    public Dialog() {
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setModal(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);

        buttonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onOK();
            }
        });

        buttonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        });

// call onCancel() when cross is clicked
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        });

// call onCancel() on ESCAPE
        contentPane.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    }

    private void onOK() {
// add your code here
        dispose();
    }

    private void onCancel() {
// add your code here if necessary
        dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как я понял .app для мака тоже самое что и .exe для винды...

в java свой формат приложений а именно .class и .jar последний это zip архив с набором .class и другой информации

в винде есть способы из .jar получить "чистый .exe" или ".exe с запиханными внутрь .jar и JRE" наверно есть что-то подобное и для мака

в любом случае вы можете собрать .jar и запускать его на любой ОС

для сборки jar'ника в IDEA нужно идти File->Project Structure->Artifacts там нажать add->Jar и настроить сборку jar'ника (в принципе там есть автонастройка)

после этого зайти в Build->Build Artifacts, дальше выскочит окошко  с выбором действий (собрать,удалить и т.п.)

p.s. для запуска на другой машине нужно иметь JRE той же или большей версии чем байт-код в jar'нике. Запускается всё так **>`java -jar programm_name.jar`** как правило .jar файл уже ассоциирован и запускается двойным кликом.

Comment: И если jar совсем непонятно как собирать, можно просто запускать class файлы.
Примерно так:

    java -classpath ./bin ManClass

*./bin* - это путь к директории  которую собираются class файлы
*ManClass* - это полное имя Main класса (у которого viod main(String[] args) определена)

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, ну и в дополнение можно сказать что jar файл можно сделать исполняемым, добавив нужные строки в META-файл.